# How to run certain parts of a program on a different Thread and reference variables to Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, process, thread-sleep

So instead of "sleeping" a thread, as in `Thread.sleep();` to merely allow the processes to run on another thread and make the new thread sleep with `Thread.sleep();` but not the original `Thread`. Is this possible?

Here is my method that I want to run on a new `Thread` called `processesThread`:

```
    private void Processes() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        // New Thread "processesThread" will start here.

        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        List<Process> processes = new ArrayList<Process>();

        // "runnableTogether" will be the number that the user inputs in the GUI.

        switch (runnableTogether) {

            case 4:
                processes.add(rt.exec("C:/Windows/System32/SoundRecorder.exe"));
            case 3:
                processes.add(rt.exec("C:/Windows/System32/taskmgr.exe"));
            case 2:
                processes.add(rt.exec("C:/Windows/System32/notepad.exe"));
            case 1:
                processes.add(rt.exec("C:/Windows/System32/calc.exe"));
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                destroyProcesses(processes);

                break;

            default:

                System.exit(0);

                break;

        }

        // New Thread "processesThread" will end here.

    }
```

Is this possible? And if so, how?

I have researched starting new `Threads`, but I can't quite figure out how to get it to work with my program.

EDIT: I was hoping to use something similar to this approach:

```
Thread processesThread = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        // Code here.
    }
};
processesThread.start();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to do here, but I'd recommend reading about the ExecutorService (http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/java-thread-pool-example-using-executors-and-threadpoolexecutor.html?ModPagespeed=noscript) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104676/java-executor-best-practices) and some official documenation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), maybe that can help you, but you need to clarify what you're trying to do :)

Comment: @AlejandroVK Basically, I don't want the thread that the majority of my program runs on, to sleep. Just the new thread.

Comment: Have a look at the provided links earlier, they will help you in your scenario, where you need to have a pool of threads that can be controlled by a manager. That's a perfect scenario for the Executor. Otherwise, you can implement this yourself, create a Thread manager that can sleep/start/stop each thread based on whatever criteria you specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question right, you want to know how to sleep other threads while the current thread remains in running state. You can use `wait` and `notify`.

Here is an example;

```
final Object mon = ...;
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (mon) {
            try {
                mon.wait(); //blocks the t1 thread
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //
            }
        }
    }
});
```

`mon.wait()` blocks the t1 thread until another thread invokes `mon.notify()` to wake the thread that is waiting on the `mon` object. You can also call `mon.notifyAll()` if more than one thread is waiting on the monitor - this will wake all of them up. However, only one of the threads will be able to grab the monitor (remember that the wait is in a synchronized block) and carry on - the others will then be blocked until they can acquire the monitor's lock.

Comment: Would you mind if I gave you a PasteBin link to show you my entire program? It would be so much easier! Maybe you could show me how I would go about implementing your approach?