# Is it good to run Http Server or infinite duration tasks in ExecutorService thread

Tags: java, executorservice, java-threads

I have a java application which runs multiple tasks infinitely. Say task FileRead reads a file repeatedly and tried to find new info and process that. Second task is http server. I am using ExecutorService to run both of those tasks in separate thread.

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2, factory);
threadPool.execute(new FileRead());
threadPool.execute(new JettyServer(port));
```

Is there any issues in this snippet?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104676/java-executor-best-practices-for-tasks-that-should-run-forever

Answer (score 1):

Yes, let the pool manage resources for you, from the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html):

Thread pools address two different problems: they usually provide improved performance when executing large numbers of asynchronous tasks, due to reduced per-task invocation overhead, **and they provide a means of bounding and managing the resources, including threads, consumed when executing a collection of tasks**. Each ThreadPoolExecutor also maintains some basic statistics, such as the number of c

Comment: What about `threadpool.shutDown(); threadpool.awaitTermination()`? Is it advisable to use them in this case? Since those are infinite threads, awaitTermination will interrupt the process.